# (Using Julia) How can I reduce my data matrix by averaging values from the same hour?

Tags: matrix, timestamp, julia, mean, sample

I am trying to reduce the size of my data and I cannot make it work. I have data points taken every minute over 1 month. I want to reduce this data to have one sample for every hour. The problem is: Some of my runs have "NA" value, so I delete these rows. There is not exactly 60 points for every hour - it varies.

I have a 'Timestamp' column. I have used this to make a 'datehour' column which has the same value if the data set has the same date and hour. I want to average all the values with the same 'datehour' value.

How can I do this? I have tried using the if and for loop below, but it takes so long to run.

Thanks for all your help! I am new to Julia and come from a Matlab background.

======= CODE ==========

```
uniquedatehour=unique(datehour,1)

index=[]
avedata=reshape([],0,length(alldata[1,:]))

for j in uniquedatehour
    for i in 1:length(datehour)

        if datehour[i]==j
            index=vcat(index,i)
        else
            rows=alldata[index,:]
            rows=convert(Array{Float64,2},rows)
            avehour=mean(rows,1)
            avedata=vcat(avedata,avehour)
            index=[]
            continue
        end
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several layers to optimizing this code. I am assuming that your data is sorted on `datehour` (your code assumes this).

#### Layer one: general recommendation

Wrap your code in a function. Executing code in global scope in Julia is much slower than within a function. By wrapping it make sure to either pass data to your function as arguments or if data is in global scope it should be qualified with `const`;

#### Layer two: recommendations to your algorithm

1. Statement like `[]` creates an array of type `Any` which is slow, you should use type qualifier like `index=Int[]` to make it fast;
2. Using `vcat` like `index=vcat(index,i)` is inefficient, it is better to do `push!(index, i)` in place;
3. It is better to preallocate `avedata` with e.g. `fill(NA, length(uniquedatehour), size(alldata, 2))` and assign values to an existing matrix than to do `vcat` on it;
4. Your code will produce incorrect results if I am not mistaken as it will not catch the last entry of `uniquedatehour` vector (assume it has only one element and check what happens - `avedata` will have zero rows)
5. Line `rows=convert(Array{Float64,2},rows)` is probably not needed at all. If `alldata` is not `Matrix{Float64}` it is better to convert it at the beginning with `Matrix{Float64}(alldata)`;
6. You can change line `rows=alldata[index,:]` to a view like `view(alldata, index, :)` to avoid allocation;
7. In general you can avoid creation of `index` vector as it is enough that you remember start `s` and end `e` position of the range of the same values and then use range `s:e` to select rows you want.

If you correct those things please post your updated code and maybe I can help further as there is still room for improvement but requires a bit different algorithmic approach (but maybe you will prefer option below for simplicity).

#### Layer three: how I would do it

I would use `DataFrames` package to handle this problem like this:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(alldata) # assuming alldata is Matrix{Float64}, otherwise convert it here
df[:grouping] = datehour
agg = aggregate(df, :grouping, mean) # maybe this is all what you need if DataFrame is OK for you
Matrix(agg[2:end]) # here is how you can convert DataFrame back to a matrix
```

This is not the fastest solution (as it converts to a `DataFrame` and back but it is much simpler for me).